# Sort by backcolor on Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview like this:

[image]

I change backcolors because if backcolor is lightcoral, its mean problem for me and I need to see on top of the gridview.

```
DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[1].Text, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        if (dt < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-102))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral;
        }
    }
DateTime dt2;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[2].Text, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out dt2))
    {
        if (dt2 < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-140))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral;
        }
    }
DateTime dt3;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[3].Text, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out dt3))
    {
        if (dt3 < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-280))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral;
        }
    }
```

I need to sort rows by backcolor like this:

[image]

Any suggestion for that?

Comment: May be this can help you http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/349026/csharp-datagridview-sorting-by-row-background-colo

Comment: Add one or more calculated Error columns based on your criteria and use them to sort and control the background color. This is a better OO design and you can  probably bind the background color to the Error column. It also allows you to sort the rows client-side eg with jQuery

Comment: In addition to @PanagiotisKanavos design I find it useful to also have a SortOrder field associated with an error state so that sorting condition states can be prioritized.